# AngularJS is it real two way data binding

Tags: angularjs

I 've just started to study Angular. Consider the following simple template:

```
<div ng-app ng-init="qty=1;cost=2">
  <div>
    Quantity: <input id="quantity" type="number" min="0" data-ng-model="qty">
  </div>
  <div>
    Costs: <input type="number" min="0" data-ng-model="cost">
  </div>
  <div>
    Total: {{qty * cost | currency}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I 've tried the following in Chrome's console:

```
var $scope = angular.element($('#quantity')).scope();
$scope.qty; //1
```

By changing the first input text from 1 to 3 manually, I am getting:

```
$scope.qty; //3
```

So far, so good! **First question**: *Why the opposite does not work?* Namely,by  setting `$scope.qty=5;` input text does not change.

**Second question**: By applying e.g. `$('#quantity').val(12);` the input text changes, however the expression in Total is not recalculated and DOM is not refreshed!

Answer (score 2):

Rules of AngularJS Club:

1. You should not use jQuery
2. You should not use jQuery
3. If you do you do
   some hacks with scope in console, don't forget to run the digest
   circle: 
   .

   **$scope.$apply()**

.

.

.

P.S.: you don't need jQuery here as well:

```
angular.element('#quantity').scope();
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to both question: Angular bind after a [$digest](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/)  phase.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following code. Each time the value change, it is reflected in the UI and vice versa.

HTML

```
<div ng-app='App'>
  <div ng-controller='AppCtrl'>
    <form ng-submit='ChangePrice()'>
      Quantity: <input id="quantity" type="number" min="0" data-ng-model="qty">
      Costs: <input type="number" min="0" data-ng-model="cost">
      Total: {{qty * cost | currency}}
      <input type='submit' value='Change Price'></input>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
 var helloApp = angular.module('App', []);
 helloApp.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.qty=10;
    $scope.cost = 2;

   $scope.ChangePrice = function(){
      $scope.cost =  $scope.cost + 1;
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the other answers, but I think they are not answering your questions.

First question: Why the opposite does not work? If you just change a variable by hand over the console no framework will know about that changes. If you change the scope you should also use `$scope.$apply()` afterwards.

Second question: By applying e.g. $('#quantity').val(12); the input text changes, however the expression in Total is not recalculated and DOM is not refreshed!
Are you sure that the DOM is not refreshed, when you apply a jQuery command on your console? This command also have the refresh inside. With that you are manipulating directly the page.

So your first command does not have a refresh inside and your second has.